# python & gtk3 - cairo_context.show_layout method is missing

Tags: python, gtk, cairo, gtk3, pango

My code looks like

```
from gi.repository import PangoCairo
from gi.repository import Gtk

class Column(Gtk.DrawingArea):
    getContext = lambda self: PangoCairo.create_context(self.get_window().cairo_create())

    ...

        cr = self.getContext()        
        cr.rectangle(0, 0, w, h)
```

And I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'rectangle'
```

The method was called `rectangle` in PyGTK (both cairo.Context and pango.Context)
But I searched in gtk3 C documentations and it seems It should be `draw_rectangle`
And none of them exist in Python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was wrong
`rectangle` is present in `cairo.Context` but not in `pango.Context`

I used `pango.Context`  because I couldn't find `show_layout` in  `cairo.Context`
Now I see the method is not in  `pango.Context`  object either
We have to use unbounded method `PangoCairo.show_layout`

Summary:

```
cr = self.get_window().cairo_create()
cr.rectangle(0, 0, w, h)
PangoCairo.show_layout(cr, layout)
```

Comment: Hmm. I'd consider having to use the unbound method to be a bug.